# How to avoid SIGSEGV Error in Insertion Sort

Tags: c, runtime-error, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement Insertion sort algorithm in C.
But all I get is *SIGSEGV error* in online IDEs and the output doesn't show up in *Code::Blocks*. How to avoid Such errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /* Here i and j are for loop counters, temp for swapping
       count  for total number of elements,array for elements*/

    int i, j, temp, count;
    printf("How many numbers are you going to enter");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    int n[20];
    printf("Enter %d elements", count);

    // storing elements in the array
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        scanf("%d", n[i]);
    }

    // Implementation of insertion sort algorithm
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        temp = n[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while(temp < n[j]) {
            n[j+1] = n[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        n[j+1] = temp;
    }

    printf("Order of sorted elements");
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d", n[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the compiler warning ? This `scanf("%d",n[i]);` --> `scanf("%d",&n[i]);` . Also what if `count` is greater than 20 ? It cause undefined behavior.

Comment: And what will be `n[-1]` i.e when `i=0`, `j = i-1` ?

Comment: Get yourself a real IDE, either Visual Studio community for Windows, or whatever is available for free under MacOS / Linux.  Being able to run your code in a controlled debug environment makes finding bugs of this sort vastly easier.  If your development environment does not stop on the line where the crash occurs, and permit you to "post mortem" inspect variables, it's time to replace it with something better.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems with your code. First of all, what is a SIGSEGV error? Well, it's another name for the good old [`Segmentation fault`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) error, which is basically the error you get when accessing invalid memory (that is, memory you are not allowed to access).

1. **tl;dr:** change `scanf("%d",n[i]);` to `scanf("%d",&n[i]);`. You're trying to read the initial values with `scanf("%d",n[i]);`, this raises a segmentation fault error because `scanf` expects **addresses** in which put the values read, but what you're really doing is passing the **value** of `n[i]` as if it were an address (which it's not, because, as you did not set any value for it yet, it's pretty much just memory garbage). More on that [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-not-used-in-scanf-function-while-reading-a-string-in-C-programming#).
2. **tl;dr:** change `int n[20];` to `int n[count]`. Your array declaration `int n[20];` is going to store at most 20 integers, what happens if someone wants to insert 21 or more values? Your program reserved a certain stack (memory) space, if you exceed that space, then you're going to stumble upon another program's space and the police (kernel) will arrest you (segmentation fault). **Hint:** try inserting 21 and then 100 values and see what happens.
3. **tl;dr:** change `for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {` to `for(i = 1; i <= count; i++) {`. This one is a logic problem with your indexes, you are starting at `i = 0` and going until `i = count - 1` which would be correct in most array iteration cases, but as `j` assumes values of indexes before `i`, you need `i` to start from `1` (so `j` is `0`, otherwise `j = -1` in the first iteration (not a valid index)).

My final code is as follows. Hope it helped, happy coding!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    /*Here i and j are for loop counters,temp for swapping
    count  for total number of elements,array for elements*/
    int i, j, temp, count;
    printf("How many numbers are you going to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d",&count);
    int n[count];
    printf("Enter %d elements\n",count);
    //storing elements in the array
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);
    }
    //Implementation of insertion sort algorithm
    for(i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        temp = n[i];
        j = i-1;
        while(temp < n[j]) {
            n[j+1] = n[j];
            j--;
        }
        n[j+1] = temp;
     }
     printf("Order of sorted elements\n");
     for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",n[i]);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** If you're having trouble with online IDEs, consider running your programs locally, it saves a lot of time, plus: you never know what kernel version or magic the online IDEs are using to run your code (trust me, when you're coding in C -- fairly low level language, these things make a difference sometimes). I like to go all root style using [`Vim`](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/intro-vim-unix-text-editor-every-hacker-should-be-familiar-with-0174674/) as text editor and [`gcc`](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html) for compiling as well as [`gdb`](http://www.gdbtutorial.com/tutorial/how-use-gdb-example) for debugging.

Comment: Thank you,I forgot to add "&" in scanf. And why wont I get an error for that mistake?

Comment: If you're using an online IDE is possible that the compiler's options are not available to you. But you can [download `gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) and specify the option `-Wall` (warn all), you should see a warning complaining about that.

`warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]`

Also, be sure to mark the answer with a check if it helped you :)